# Jenkins Warning Plugin and SonarQube Scanner

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

For my project, I want use the Warning Plugin on Jenkins. The result is a XML file. And I have a plugin SonarQube for read this file.

However, the Warning plugin is execute after the Sonar Scanner analysis. Warning plugin is in "Post build actions" and the Sonar Scanner analysis is in "Post build step". So the XML file can't be read by my SonarQube Plugin cause this file doesn't exist when the SonarQube Scanner runs.

Someone has a solution ?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another Job to read the XML in Post build actions. So in your current Job you must execute the plugin in Post build actions to create the XML. So in Post build step call the new job created. It makes the XML enable to read.